# emacs ocaml auto close comment

Tags: emacs, config

I'd like to configure my .emacs by this way :
when I type `(*` and space, I want emacs to auto close the comment like `(*  *)`.

I don't really understand how to configure .emacs files, and I even don't know if what I ask is possible.